# Help me find the device based on its label

Tags: diodes, identification, tvs

I have an SMD component containing two pads (probably in a SMC case). There is a label on the surface of the component: ***fAC15*** in one row and ***MP*** in second row. 
I suppose the component is a Transient Voltage Suppression (TVS) diode. 
Am I right?

Thank you very much for your time and effort to help me.

Sincerely,

Bojan

Comment: Most of your question is fine. The part on "Can you help me find Mouser ordering link of this component?" is not on-topic for this site.

Comment: By the way, if you google "smd code book" you'll find some useful docs for this kind of task.

Comment: OK, Fluff. I understand your point. Consequently, I removed compromising part of my question.
Thank you for your advice about googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a Fairchild SMBJ36 36V TVS. "MP" is used for both unidirectional (SMBJ36A) and bidirectional (SMBJ36CA) devices.

Comment: Thank you very much Ignacio. You helped me a lot. I did take a look into the datasheet of the component trying to figure out is my chip bidirectional or unidirectional.
Given that there is no cathode indicator on the surface of the device (color band), I believe that device I have is a bidirectional (SMBJ36CA).
Anyways, thank you very much for your help. I appreciate it.